# Load/Shunt resistor value calculation for DC-DC Converters

Tags: dc-dc-converter, load, shunt

I have DC-DC converter with rating -4KV and 1W. The unit supports current monitoring of output voltage. I would like to test the current monitoring using shunt resistor.
What should be the rating of the shunt resistor. How to calculate the desired resistor value and power rating.

Thanks

Comment: You can calculate the expected range of current. You also need to know the voltage sensitivity of whatever you're measuring it with. Then use Ohm's Law.

Comment: Also, you will need to double check the voltage capabilities of any resistors that you use. At 4kV, you'll most likely need to put several in series to make sure that they don't break over and fail.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, Thanks for input. The full load is 250uA based on the equation P=VI.